# button causing page to reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using html and jquery on my page.

In my html i have one button which when clicked will fire one function.

When page loads i call main function in document ready. Here is my code

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        main();

      });
      function main(){
             //some code goes here
      }

      function search(){
           //some logic
      }
</script>

<div>
  <button id="btnSearch" onclick="search()" >Search</button>
</div>
```

But when i click on button then it goes inside `main` function and executes code inside it. Why? It should only call function search and nothing else. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add your code inside of those functions so that we can answer.

Comment: The description of the problem and the title of the question don't seem to be the same thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default `BUTTONS` are of type `SUBMIT`, try this instead

```
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" onclick="search()" >Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. See demo

```js
      $(document).ready(function () {
        main();

      });
      function main(){
          //some code goes here
         alert('main');          
      }

      function search(){
           //some logic
           alert('search');
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btnSearch" onclick="search()" >Search</button>
</div>
```